How to Integrate a Slider Inside an Invisible Container Toggled by a Button?
As someone relatively new to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, I'm currently working on a learning project where I'm trying to include a slider component within a container that remains invisible by default and becomes visible only when a button is pressed.
I found a tutorial on YouTube (here is the source code for it) and followed the steps to integrate the slider into my page.
The issue I'm facing is that the slider functions perfectly when I place it directly within the body of the page. However, when I attempt to nest it inside an overlay container (although I'm not entirely sure if overlay is the correct term to use here), it doesn't seem to behave as expected.
Here is the code I want to merge from the tutorial


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" />
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 60%;
        height: 400px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .slides {
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .slide {
        min-width: 100%;
        position: relative;
      }

      .slide img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .slide-controls {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }

      #next-btn,
      #prev-btn {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: transparent;
        font-size: 30px;
        border: none;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
      }

      #next-btn:focus,
      #prev-btn:focus {
        outline: none;
      }

      .slide-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        font-size: 60px;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Infinite Slideshow : non-degree programmer</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slides">
        <div class="slide">
          <!-- <img src="img/slide-1.jpg" alt="" /> -->
          <div class="slide-content">
            <h1>slide-1</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <!-- <img src="img/slide-2.jpg" alt="" /> -->
          <h1>slide-2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <!-- <img src="img/slide-3.jpg" alt="" /> -->
          <h1>slide-3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <!-- <img src="img/slide-4.jpg" alt="" /> -->
          <h1>slide-4</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-controls">
        <button id="prev-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </button>
        <button id="next-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      const slideContainer = document.querySelector('.container');
      const slide = document.querySelector('.slides');
      const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next-btn');
      const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev-btn');
      const interval = 3000;

      let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
      let index = 1;
      let slideId;

      const firstClone = slides[0].cloneNode(true);
      const lastClone = slides[slides.length - 1].cloneNode(true);

      firstClone.id = 'first-clone';
      lastClone.id = 'last-clone';

      slide.append(firstClone);
      slide.prepend(lastClone);

      const slideWidth = slides[index].clientWidth;

      slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-slideWidth * index}px)`;

      console.log(slides);

      const startSlide = () => {
        slideId = setInterval(() => {
          moveToNextSlide();
        }, interval);
      };

      const getSlides = () => document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

      slide.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
        slides = getSlides();
        if (slides[index].id === firstClone.id) {
          slide.style.transition = 'none';
          index = 1;
          slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-slideWidth * index}px)`;
        }

        if (slides[index].id === lastClone.id) {
          slide.style.transition = 'none';
          index = slides.length - 2;
          slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-slideWidth * index}px)`;
        }
      });

      const moveToNextSlide = () => {
        slides = getSlides();
        if (index >= slides.length - 1) return;
        index++;
        slide.style.transition = '.7s ease-out';
        slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-slideWidth * index}px)`;
      };

      const moveToPreviousSlide = () => {
        if (index <= 0) return;
        index--;
        slide.style.transition = '.7s ease-out';
        slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-slideWidth * index}px)`;
      };

      slideContainer.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        clearInterval(slideId);
      });

      slideContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', startSlide);
      nextBtn.addEventListener('click', moveToNextSlide);
      prevBtn.addEventListener('click', moveToPreviousSlide);

      startSlide();
    </script>
  </body>

</html>



Here is my initial code:


const questionContainer = document.getElementById('question-container');
const answerContainer = document.getElementById('answer-container');
const questionInput = document.getElementById('question-input');
const answerDiv = document.getElementById('answer');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');
const clearButton = document.getElementById('clear-button');
const exploreButton = document.getElementById('explore');
const aboutButton = document.getElementById('about');
const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn');
const exploreContent = document.getElementById('explore-content');
const aboutContent = document.getElementById('about-content');

questionInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    submitButton.disabled = !questionInput.value;
});

function handleAnswerSubmission() {
    showAnswer();
    questionInput.disabled = true;
    submitButton.disabled = true;
}

function showAnswer() {
    const question = questionInput.value;
    const answer = question;
    answerDiv.innerText = answer;
    questionContainer.style.opacity = '.5';
    questionContainer.style.top = '20%';
    answerContainer.style.opacity = '1';
    answerContainer.style.top = '50%';
    answerContainer.style.visibility = 'visible';
    submitButton.disabled = false;
}

function fetchData() {
    // const apiUrl = '';
}

function handleClear() {
    const question = questionInput.value;
    questionContainer.style.opacity = '1';
    questionContainer.style.top = '40%';
    answerContainer.style.opacity = '0';
    answerContainer.style.top = '80%';
    answerContainer.style.visibility = 'visible';
    questionInput.value = question;
    questionInput.disabled = false;
    submitButton.disabled = false;
    questionInput.focus();
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', handleAnswerSubmission);
questionInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && questionInput.value && !overlay.classList.contains('active')) {
        handleAnswerSubmission();
    }
});

clearButton.addEventListener('click', handleClear);
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Escape' && !overlay.classList.contains('active')) {
        handleClear();
    }
});

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    fetchData();
});

exploreButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    showOverlay(exploreContent);
});

aboutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    showOverlay(aboutContent);
});

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hideOverlay();
});


function showOverlay(content) {
    overlay.style.display = 'flex'; // Display the overlay
    overlay.classList.add('active'); // Add the active class to start transition

    // Hide all content initially
    exploreContent.style.display = 'none';
    aboutContent.style.display = 'none';

    // Show the corresponding content
    content.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideOverlay() {
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
    setTimeout(() => {
        overlay.style.display = 'none';
        exploreContent.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the content
        aboutContent.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the content
    }, 500); // Adjust this time to match the CSS transition duration
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  /*font-size: 2em;*/
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #444444;
  height: 100vh
}

#answer-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  max-width: 80%;
  width: auto;
  transition: opacity 1.15s ease, top 1.15s ease;
}

#question-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 65%;
  height: auto;
  transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s ease;
}

#question-input {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  resize: none;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#submit-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#clear-button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#clear-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: rgb(185, 28, 28);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#clear-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(172, 26, 26);
}

#submit-button:enabled {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(28, 185, 62);
  color: white;
}

#answer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #question-input {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

.fab-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 997;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fab-icon-holder {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #016fb9;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.fab-icon-holder:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.fab-icon-holder i {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.fab {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #016fb9;
}

.fab-options {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: 20% bottom;
}

.fab:hover+.fab-options,
.fab-options:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.fab-options li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fab-label {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  align-self: center;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* Initially transparent */
  z-index: 998;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  /* Smooth transition effect */
  display: none;
  /* Initially hidden */
}

.overlay.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* Semi-transparent background */
  opacity: 1;
  /* Display when active */
}

.explore-content,
.about-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: none;
  /* Initially hidden */
  z-index: 999;
  color: black;
  width: 90%;
  /* Set the width to 80% of the screen */
  height: 50%;
  /* Set the width to 80% of the screen */
}

#closeBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-circle-xmark {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="question-container">
      <input type="search" id="question-input" placeholder="ask your question" required>
      <button id="submit-button" disabled>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="answer-container">
      <div id="answer"></div>
      <div id="clear-button-container">
        <button id="clear-button">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fab-container">
      <div class="fab fab-icon-holder">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </div>

      <ul class="fab-options">
        <li id="explore">
          <span class="fab-label">questions list</span>
          <div class="fab-icon-holder">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="about">
          <span class="fab-label">about</span>
          <div class="fab-icon-holder">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-address-card"></i>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
      <div id="closeBtn">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="explore-content" id="explore-content">
        <!-- Slider HTML -->
        <p>I want the slider to be here</p>
        <!-- End of Slider HTML -->
      </div>
      <div class="about-content" id="about-content">
        <!-- Your content goes here -->
        <p>This is the about section.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>




First step make sure your slider work first outside popup, see the code work perfectly then copy it on the popup, if you have a multiple popup. But If you want to use only one popup can be use for all toggle event button you need some modification on javascript side for changeing the popup content and start and destroy the event on popup show and hide.

Thank you for your response. I've already tested the code separately, and it worked perfectly. However, when I integrated it into the container where it should reside, the slider functionality ceased to work. Although I could interact with the buttons and observed their behavior while debugging, the slider itself did not slide @TaurusSilver

I even attempted to implement this slider functionality using Tiny Slider, but unfortunately, I wasn't successful. @TaurusSilver

Yeah but when you click the button do some javascript event handler that can change the tiny slider object being invoke, let said that you want to change the slide contant that get from a database. So you need fetch to the server to grab the data you need and than rander it into a javascript object or content html (this depend how the slider works or your preference) before you init new one or update the slider data plugins.
